# Remote Server for a windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

am developing a windows phone app which requires registration and keeping track of the users location.The app also requires to store and retrieve data from the server. The problem is that i dont know anything about how to make a remote database server. Will somebody please explain to me how its done and links are also welcomed.

Comment: _"How to write an app that talks to a remote database"_ is a bit too broad for an SO Q&A. You can start by reading about webservices, which is the common way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad question so I'll address it at a high level but you have quite a bit to learn.

System Components

Windows Phone App -> Web Service -> Database

Your Windows Phone app should talk to a Web Service and then your Web Service will talk to your Data Store which could be a Database.

Your Web Service could be implemented using SOAP or REST.  If you don't know, you should start with REST as it is much easier to get started.  ASP.NET Web API is one option for implementing a REST service.  You should be able to File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Web API and have a sample generated to get you started.

The Database can be created using SQL Server, MY Sql, or any other for that matter.  You will need to connect your Web Service to your Database by opening a connection to the database and then either sending SQL statements to the database or calling stored procedures in the database.  .NET provides ADO.NET for low level operations against the database and if you are a beginner this is where you should start.  You NEED to understand the low level stuff before graduating to an abstraction ORM such as Entity Framework or (N)Hibernate.

I suggest that you look for a sample project that demonstrates how to do all of this.  Going to Plural Sight and watching there videos on these topics would be the best way to get started and then pick up a few books.

Lastly, you will need a place to host the database and the Web Service.  Azure provide great options for this.  You can create a WebSite for free to start that would host your ASP.NET Web API or any Web Service technology for the most part.  If you are not a fan of the Free offering from Azure you should look at Amazon's Micro Server to start.

Good Luck & Have fun,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an application of sorts. For instance you can write simple php scripts that will take query string ( /post values) and submit those values to the DB/and or retrive results and serve them as response. Or you can create a proper web service using Java/.Net/php etc.

Do you have experience using any relational database software such as MS Sql or MySql etc? And do you have any exparience on php/.net/java ?

depending on your answers you can create a simple web application or a web service using your current skill sets or you can just go to a developer hiring web site and ask someone to do it for you.